Integration Techniques: Using Integration by Parts After Substitution
I'm working on the integral of $\int \frac{xe^x}{(1+e^x)^3} dx$ and I've used the substitution $u = e^x$ to simplify it to: $$\int \frac{\ln(u)}{(1+u)^3} du$$ Now, I'm wondering if it's valid to use integration by parts on this new expression. Can I apply integration by parts after using substitution? Any insights or examples would be appreciated. Thank you!

Yes why not. It's just a new variable. But don't forget to substitute back the original value of u in the form of x after operation

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

As I tell my students - integration techniques are meant to be used in combination with each other.

Let's work through your problem step by step. First you have to apply IBP like you suggested.
What function is best to integrate and differentiate ? (note that it will end up easier if you choose something that let's you have a rational function which in general is easier to deal with).
By IBP (differentiate $\ln(x)$ and integrate $\frac{1}{(1+u)^3}$):
$$\mathcal{I}=\frac{-\ln(u)}{2(1+u)^2}+\int \frac{1}{2u(1+u)^2} \ du$$
Let's compute the integral to the right (we shall denote $\mathcal{J}$)
$$\mathcal{J}=\int \frac{1+u-u}{2u(1+u)^2}$$
Splitting fractions:
$$=\int \frac{1}{2u(1+u)} \ du - \int \frac{1}{2(1+u)^2} \ du$$
By applying the change of variables $v=u+1$ to the right integral it comes around to basic integration. Now we could apply partial fractions on the left term, but we will proceed the following way:
$$=\int \frac{1+u-u}{2u(1+u)} \ du - \int \frac{1}{2(1+u)^2} \ du$$
$$=\int \frac{1+u-u}{2u(1+u)} \ du + \frac{1}{2(u+1)}$$
$$=\int \frac{1}{2u} \ du - \int \frac{1}{2(u+1)} \ du + \frac{1}{2(u+1)} $$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln\biggr(\frac{u}{u+1} \biggr) + \frac{1}{2(u+1)} + C$$
Our final answer becomes:
$$ \mathcal{I}=\frac{-\ln(u)}{2(1+u)^2}+\mathcal{J}$$
$$=\frac{-\ln(u)}{2(1+u)^2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\biggr(\frac{u}{u+1}\biggr) + \frac{1}{2(u+1)} + C$$
Now you only need to plug the initial change of variables.

Via integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{x e^x}{\left(1+e^x\right)^3} d x 
= & -\frac{1}{2} \int x d\left(\frac{1}{\left(1+e^x\right)^2}\right) \\
= & -\frac{x}{2\left(1+e^x\right)^2}+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\left(1+e^x\right)^2} d x \\
= & -\frac{x}{2\left(1+e^x\right)^2}+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1+e^x-e^x}{\left(1+e^x\right)^2} d x \\
= & -\frac{x}{2\left(1+e^x\right)^2}+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d x}{1+e^x} -\frac{1}{2}  \int \frac{e^x}{\left(1+e^x\right)^2} \\
= & -\frac{x}{2\left(1+e^x\right)^2}+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1} d x+\frac{1}{2\left(1+e^x\right)} \\
= & -\frac{x}{2\left(1+e^x\right)^2}-\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(e^{-x}+1\right)+\frac{1}{2\left(1+e^x\right)}+C\\=& \frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{x}{\left(1+e^x\right)^2}-\ln \left(1+e^x\right)+x+\frac{1}{1+e^x}\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$
